# Font Awesome not working in Firefox but works in Chrome and Edge

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I am having trouble with this site: https://garrysun.com/ and the icons for the cart and the down arrows on the nav menu don't show up in firefox but they do in Edge and Chrome.

I tried adding `<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">` to the  section but it didn't work. I even removed the existing code and added this and then I got the arrows in firefox but the cart icon broke across all browsers.

Any suggestions?

Comment: How is your question going to remain relevant for future visitors after the problem gets fixed on the linked website? Note I can't repro your issue on FF Quantum 59.0.1 (64-bit) on Ubuntu, either. Add the FF tag, specify your browser version and OS and at least add a picture with the broken cart, if you can't reproduce it in a [mcve] inside the question.

Answer (score 0):

I can see both the fa-shopping-bag and the down arrow next to "All Categories" in that nav dropdown (assuming that's what you referring to). All the other font awesomeness on the page looks okay to me... FireFox 59.0.2 on MacOS...

Comment: How is not being able to repro the issue an answer? Please read [answer].